# Stop gitkraken from scanning my disk for git repositories

Tags: gitkraken

I am using gitkraken V2.0.1 and it is auto scanning my disks for git repos, even those in my backup folders. How can I stop gitkraken from doing this?

Answer (score 0):

In `Preferences` -> `General`, you can specify a `Project Directory`, which GitKraken scans for projects recursively.

[image]

With just `C:\` as in this example, it will scan the entire disk. Try using something more restrictive to avoid your backups etc. from being included.

Comment: This is not working in Ubuntu. I already have the project directory to an obscure folder. But, my entire home folder is getting scanned.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem even though my 'projectsDirectory' in Preferences -> General had not changed since updating to 2.0. Re-setting the projects directory again to the same folder seemed to fix the problem.